Coinbase Wallet holds my Btc on the Bitcoin Network requiring me to add the Bitcoin Network as a custom without providing RPC URL or Block Explorer
I have 3 Wallets in Coinbase Wallet holding my Btc on the Bitcoin Network.  To access my assets I  have to add the Bitcoin Network to Coinbase wallet as a custom network. Coinbase Wallet has not provided me with the  information to add the Bitcoin Network mainnet (the RPC URL, Chain id and Block Explorer URL) or access my assets. When I  initially opened and deposited to the Wallets I was only given a testnet Network key for viewing the assets. Coinbase Wallet has refused to provide me with the mainnet addition information since April, 2024. Where can I obtain the needed information.


When I initially opened and deposited to the Wallets I was only given a testnet Network key for viewing the assets

Frankly, to me, this looks completely abnormal and like a scam perpetrated by some criminal posing as an assistant or fake broker etc.
What you describe is unlike what I would expect of any normal experience with the real Coinbase.
There's a chance I am unduly sceptical but without further information it looks extremely fishy.
